# segment paragraph to sentences

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, text-segmentation

I'm trying to segment a paragraph to sentences. I selected '.', '?' and '!' as the segmentation symbols. I tried:

```
format = r'((! )|(. )|(? ))'
delimiter = re.compile(format)
s = delimiter.split(line)
```

but it gives me `sre_constants.error: unexpected end of pattern`

I also tried

```
format = [r'(! )',r'(? )',r'(. )']
delimiter = re.compile(r'|'.join(format))
```

it also causes error.

What's wrong with my method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` (wildcard) and `?` (zero or one, quantifier) are special regex characters, you need to escape them to use them literally.

However, in your case it would be much simpler to use a character class (inside which these characters aren't special anymore):

```
split(r'[!.?] ')
```

A character class `[...]` stands for "one character, any of the ones included inside the character class".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, I would include the space too (usually there is a space after each sentence, if I use [.?!] directly, for every sentence I printed out, (i) there is a space at the front, (ii) "What do you mean?"said by Mary will be segmented to two sentences instead of one)

Comment: Saw your update. it works. Thanks a lot! Will accept in 3 min as required :)

Comment: @ChuNan: Updated indeed. Glad I could help

Comment: Upvoting for short and sweet. I have been noticing your fine regex style. Yes, load up these character classes! `[[?*+.-]` :)